# Чтение русского текста из File

Tags: java, android

**Задача: скачать текст из Firebase и продемонстрировать его в log'ах.**

Скачиваю текстовый файл с помощью кода:

```
            //Скачиваие файла
            // Сначала получаем доступ к Хранилищу
            FirebaseStorage storage2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

            // Создаем ссылку на рут
            StorageReference storageRef2 = storage2.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://XXX");
            StorageReference TextPathReference = storageRef2.child("text/" + "2.txt");

            final File TextFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "2.txt");

            TextPathReference.getFile(TextFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
                {
                    // Файл был скачан
                    Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Текстовый файл был скачан"); //Пишет в лог
                    File file = new File(TextFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    String [] loadText = Load(file);
                    String finalString = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < loadText.length; i++)
                    {
                        finalString += loadText[i]+ System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    }
                    Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Текст в файле: " + finalString); //Пишет в лог
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Ошибка
                    Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Ошибка"); //Пишет в лог

                }
            });
```

где `Load`:

```
public static String[] Load(File file)
    {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String test;
        int anzahl=0;
        try
        {
            while ((test=br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                anzahl++;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        try
        {
            fis.getChannel().position(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        String[] array = new String[anzahl];

        String line;
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                array[i] = line;
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return array;
    }
```

> В результате в `Log` пишется текст (например: `Текст в файле: hello world`)

**Проблема: если текст в файле записан русскими буквами, то в результате в логах надпись такого типа: (например: `Текст в файле: ������ ���`)**

Как перевести символы "�" в русские буквы?

Comment: дайте ссылку на ваш текстовый файл

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Не помогло. Всё равно символы "�".

Comment: File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings IDE Encoding и Project Encoding установить нужную кодировку  для Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой.
Тоже все писали про UTF-8, и тоже не помогло.
Нашёл сайт: http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/ruschars/ruschars.html

И на их сайте нашёл такую кодировку: 
Windows-1251 |  Windows (Ansi-кодировка)    | **Cp1251**

Мне помогло, если не поможет попробуй другие кодировки из их списка.

Answer (score 0):

Если файл небольшой, самый простой способ чтения - использовать `new String`

```java
File file = new File(address);
try {
     byte[] arrayBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
     String text = new String(arrayBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
```

Если используется стандартный блокнот как в ОС Windows в качестве `Log` файла, то он должен быть сохранён с кодировкой UTF-8. По умолчанию у него кодировка ANSI. Если вы создаёте файл вручную, обратите внимание в какой кодировке вы его сохраняете: Меню "Файл" --> "Сохранить как".

Для записи в файл, используйте `FileWriter` Например:

```java
    try {
         FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, true);
         fileWriter.append(text);
         fileWriter.flush();
         fileWriter.close();
        }
         catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Текстовый файл нужно создавать не через блокнот, а через другой текстовый редактор. В моём случае мне помог Notepad++.

Comment: Не имеет разницы где вы создаете текстовый документ, разные текстовые процессоры могут использовать разные кодировки по умолчанию. BufferedReader или другие классы могут получать определенные кодировки для работы с символами.